# POI formula evaluation performance

Tags: apache-poi

I am using XLS format of the excel file which consists of formula in it.
For evaluating the formula I am using FormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellEnum() method (I using POI 3.16) but this is taking around 10sec to evaluate the formula in a cell. I tried with HSSFWorkbook.evaluateAllFormulaCells but that is degrading the performance. Is there a way I can improve the time taken by for formula evaluation by POI. Thanks for your help. Using JDK6 and running on Tomcat7.

Comment: What is the problematic formula?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use .evaluate()/evaluateAll()?

Answer (score -1):

I use FormulaEvaluator class and it works fast and fine, for both HSSF and XSSF.
For example :

```
FormulaEvaluator eval = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
CellValue cellValue = eval.evaluate(cell);
```